# webDialog "CURRENT GOALS" header but no button to authorize or cancel

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog

I am new to Facebook SDK. I am adding the Facebook login in my Android app using Facebook SDK 3.0.1. A Facebook webDialog pop-up for login. Today I found a strange behaviour that is different from that yesterday.

After entering an account name and password and press Login button in the webDialog, it finally shows "CURRENT GOALS" in the header requesting add friends, enter locations, etc. The body shows "(YOUR_APP) would like to access your public profile and friend list". But there is no more button to authorize or cancel. From the Eclipse LogCat, the current session state from Session.StatusCallback() is OPENING. As a result, user cannot complete the login process.

So how do I pass the dialog to complete the login process successfully? If I press the upper-left corner close button or back button, the dialog closes. The session state would become CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.

Yesterday, when the same account login, the webDalog finally show "You have already authorized (YOURAPP)" and a Cancel and OK buttons exist. If user press OK, the dialog closes, and Session.StatusCallback() calls out session state becomes OPENED. Thus user complete the login process successfully.

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am getting similar problem, its impossible to test my app due to this web dialog

Comment: Any solution for this issues? same issue in my android application as well.

Comment: But it is working fine in tablets as the screen height is large when compared to device.

Comment: I have no solution so far. It seems to be problem from the Facebook webDialog. Can any Facebook developer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found and posted a workaround at: [current goals hides facebook ok button during Facebook authorization in a web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661144/current-goals-hides-facebook-ok-button-during-facebook-authorization-in-a-web-vi/16807505#16807505)

In the FaceBookSDK I modified com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java, so that once the web dialog was loaded it would look for the block that contains "Current Goals" and hide it (if it exists). Once you do that, the buttons are visible again (at least they were for me).

In com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java:

```
private class DialogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    // ... other methods ...

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!isDetached) {
            spinner.dismiss();
        }
        /*
         * Once web view is fully loaded, set the contentFrameLayout background to be transparent
         * and make visible the 'x' image.
         */
        contentFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        crossImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // I don't know how to highlight in the code block
        // So I just add this extra long comment to make it obvious
        // Add a javascript call to hide that element, if it exists
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:try{ document.getElementById('nux-missions-bar').style.display='none'; } catch (e) {}");
        // End changes           
    }
```