# Facebook login problems current goals screen not generating oath token

Tags: android, facebook-login, android-facebook

I am a newbie and devleoping an app which uses facebook login and the details which we get after logging from facebook for further interactions. Two days back it was running fine but today it stopped running its just showing CURRENT GOALS screen and no button to do ok or cancel or anything of that sort. Just see this link

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&type=user_agent&client_id=307234779396415&ret=login&ext=1368864103&hash=AeZ9mMBQfC22WXj_&refid=9&_rdr

I am using the Facebook Dialog class to achieve the login but in the facebook sdk also  the graphSampleApi sample project is running with same problem.
Please help I need to the login badly and my project deadline is today. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this simplier URL for log in ::

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=307234779396415&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=touch&scope=publish_stream
```

Comment: Still same problem. Please check it in your system browser in this screen also the ok and cancel buttons are almost hidden behind the screen at the bottom..... Is it creating problem for everyone or only for me?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this similar/duplicate question:  [FbDialog doesn't show full content on smaller devices](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16647458/fbdialog-doesnt-show-full-content-on-smaller-devices)

Basically, it looks like Facebook changed the code in these web dialogs and something in their javascript is not executing properly on some Android devices.   The Cancel/OK buttons are there in the page content, but hidden, and the javascript is failing before the buttons are shown.

Comment: Problem solved I just changed my app permission which was running in sandbox mode> I just changed it to live mode and suddenly everything started working fine. I think there was a problem with fb sdk which is solved by now.....

Answer (score 0):

You can inject JavaScript to hide the "Current Goals" until FaceBook fixes their API.

See my answer here for details:
[webDialog "CURRENT GOALS" header but no button to authorize or cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559120/facebook-login-webdialog-current-goals-header-but-no-button-to-authorize-or-ca/16807614#16807614)