# FbDialog doesn't show full content on smaller devices

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Steps to repro

- Log in to FB with new FB account I can see the webdialog showing me
  current goals and other stuff, but I can not see Authorize OK cancel
  buttons(probably moved down). I can not scroll to see those buttons

Can any one suggest me quick fix, without necessarily updating FB SDK

Comment: Shri are you solve this issue ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar No, I am still waiting from FB to get some worthy info

Comment: Okay, If you find some solution please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just posted this workaround to: [webDialog "CURRENT GOALS" header but no button to authorize or cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559120/facebook-login-webdialog-current-goals-header-but-no-button-to-authorize-or-ca/16807614#16807614)

In the FaceBookSDK I modified com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java, so that once the web dialog was loaded it would look for the block that contains "Current Goals" and hide it (if it exists). Once you do that, the buttons are visible again (at least they were for me).

In com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java:

private class DialogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
// ... other methods ...

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if (!isDetached) {
        spinner.dismiss();
    }
    /*
     * Once web view is fully loaded, set the contentFrameLayout background to be transparent
     * and make visible the 'x' image.
     */
    contentFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    crossImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // I don't know how to highlight in the code block
    // So I just add this extra long comment to make it obvious
    // Add a javascript call to hide that element, if it exists
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:try{ document.getElementById('nux-missions-bar').style.display='none'; } catch (e) {}");
    // End changes           
}
```

This should help, at least until FaceBook fixes the API.

Comment: This works! Thanks a ton, but I think you have to edit the post little bit, you have to replace the webview with view. This seems to be right answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this is affecting Facebook SDK 2 and 3 in Android.  I can't speak to iOS.  For some reason, scrollbars are disabled in their WebDialog.java code so I tried enabling scrollbars in setUpWebView. Scrollbars now appear in this prompt but the OK and Cancel buttons aren't there.  So, it's not a case of the buttons being off-screen and unreachable but rather the buttons aren't part of the content at all when the Current Goals section is included.

It looks like this is a problem Facebook will need to resolve on their side.

Comment: Digging further, Current Goals and the Cancel/OK buttons are both there in the page source. Javascript is supposed to hide the current goals and show the buttons but it isn't executing correctly in Android's webview the SDK uses for the WebDialog.  

If you disable javascript in their WebDialog code, the content loads and you see both the Current Goals and the buttons...and the OK button works.  But obviously, I can't leave it this way and ship my app.  They'll need to tweak the javascript they are sending down.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I see the OK/Cancel buttons for a split of second, and they are move down I guess, I can see the OK/Cancel buttons on bigger device, hence I don't think it is problem with content.

Comment: I think it's going to depend on the version of Android and/or its underlying webkit version.  Or it might fire different javascript based on viewport size and if it thinks both Current Goals and the buttons can fit at once?  I'm not sure, but I have a few devices where this is not working properly and a few where it is working.

Comment: Regardless, Facebook SDK 2 and 3 are both affected and I've changed nothing on my app side.  There are 3 versions of this question in this Stackoverflow and they are all posted since May 18th.  Something changed on the Facebook side.

Comment: Just chiming in to confirm that this issue also affects granting permissions for Facebook App on iOS 5.x and 6.x using the v3.5.1 Facebook SDK (not using the iOS 6.0 system wide login).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem which is solved. I just changed my app permission which was running in sandbox mode> I just changed it to live mode and suddenly everything started working fine. I think there was a problem with fb sdk which is solved by now.....

Comment: where did you change this mode?

Comment: I changed this mode in developer.facebook.com there we create app to get the facebook api key. There is an option to keep your app in sandbox mode or in live mode..... I hope this helps you too.

Comment: @Piezotron try to login with some different account and check once. I was loging in with a newly created account which was creating a problem for me. So try with some other fb account.