# current goals hides facebook ok button during Facebook authorization in a web view

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

We are using the latest Facebook iOS SDK (3.5) and have the following problem with webview login. Current goals tab hides facebook ok and cancel button so the user is not able to authorize the app.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Login using Facebook SDK UIWebView
2) "You have already authorized ..." text appears
3) Both OK and Cancel button hidden and the view is NOT scrollable.

Is there a workaround to this issue?

------------- UPDATE -------------

The issue is now FIXED by Facebook.

Comment: Apparently FB is aware of this problem: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486953708025816 and apparently is not in hurry to fix it.

Comment: Just received  an update from FB: 
We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed soon. Stay tuned. (keeping my fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help IOS users, but I can tell you how I fixed this for my App in Android in case anyone else runs across this bug (and perhaps someone can translate this fix to IOS).

In the FaceBookSDK I modified com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java, so that once the web dialog was loaded it would look for the "Current Goals" block and hide it (if it exists).

In com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java:

```
private class DialogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    // ... other methods ...

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!isDetached) {
            spinner.dismiss();
        }
        /*
         * Once web view is fully loaded, set the contentFrameLayout background to be transparent
         * and make visible the 'x' image.
         */
        contentFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        crossImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // I don't know how to highlight in the code block
        // So I just add this extra long comment to make it obvious
        // Add a javascript call to hide that element, if it exists
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:try{ document.getElementById('nux-missions-bar').style.display='none'; } catch (e) {}");
        // End changes           
    }
```